# Order of $[m]$ for any $m \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{Z}_n = \mathbb{Z} / n\mathbb{Z}$.
> For $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, what is the order of $[m]$?

To my understanding, quiet naive question, but I cannot really find out how to phrase it. 
This is what I tried: 
Suppose the order is k, then $k[m] = [km] = [0]$ by definition of order, which forces either $k=0$ or $m=0$. The latter gives order of $[0]$ (is this even a valid statement?), and the former is just the order doesn't exists, i.e. infinity. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: It is not true that either $k=0$ or $m=0$. The element $[km]=[0]$ just means that $km$ is a multiple of $n$. For example, when $n=6$ and $m=3$, we get $k=2$. I hope that makes sense!

Comment: @CoherentSheaf That make sense...I totally overlooked that, my bad.

Comment: By the linked dupe  $\,km\equiv0\pmod{\!n}\iff n\mid km\iff  n/\gcd(n,m)\mid k \iff {\rm lcm}(n,m)/m\mid k.\ $ (this is presuming you seek the *additive* order, as written).

Comment: Well, you first have to ensure that $m$ and $n$ are coprime. You can then prove that $m$ must possess an order by noting that there are finitely many congruence classes and appealing to the pigeonhole principle. But the question itself is a little strange, as it asks you to find the order of $m$ for _any_ $m$ (and presumably any $n$), but of course they will not all have the same order for any given value of $n$...

Comment: @H.sap The question as written concerns the *additive* order, i.e. the order in the additive group $\Bbb Z.\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque thanks a lot for the suggestion! I get it now. 
I actually have to solve quiet similar in another part of the question (to find all generator of $\mathbb{Z}_n$). I was just very confused about the wording originally.